HTML - Button perde funcionalidade após clique
Montei um menu com button que, ao clicar, abre a href na div determinada.
Ocorre que nenhum deles funciona mais após a div Conteudo ser carregada.
Estou usando html e bootstrap.
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="bi bi-person-circle"></i> Pacientes
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="NovoPaciente.php#Conteudo"> Novo </a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="AtualizaPaciente.php#Conteudo"> Atualiza dados </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
